# Check if achievement is unlocked

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can i tell if a achievement on game center is unlocked? Im trying to use this code,
but the achievement does not get unlocked when total_top is equal or larger than 63.

Can anyone help me?

```
[GKAchievement loadAchievementsWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error)         
{
            if(error != NULL) { }            
            for (GKAchievement* achievement in scores) {
                if (([achievement.identifier isEqualToString:kAchSixtyThree]) && (achievement.percentComplete < 99) && (total_top >= 63)) {
                    NSLog(@"a: %@", achievement.identifier);

                    achievement.percentComplete = 100.0;
                    achievement.showsCompletionBanner = YES;

                    [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                        if (error != nil) {}
                    }];
                }
}];
```